# How to auto redirect to a mobile site

Tags: mobile

How can I make an auto redirect on my website to my mobile website, when visited from a mobile browser. I would rather not have to create a database.

Comment: From a UX point of view it might be better to provide a header saying "Hey, we think you're viewing this on a phone. Here's a link to our mobile site" rather than forcing an automatic redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Without platform information, it's difficult to make a specific recommendation. The general advice is match some string in the User-Agent that tells you it's a mobile browser (probably multiple patterns will be required) and generate a [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) response.

EDIT: A google search turns up [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) very comprehensive page on User-Agent strings for mobile devices. Suffice to say, you probably want to restrict your list of patterns to devices you specifically intend to target, and let the rest fall back to your main site.

Answer (score 2):

you should check for user agent header via a regexp to find out if it is some kind of mobile devices or not.

take a look here http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how khanacademy does it in python:

```
def user_agent(self):
    return str(self.request.headers['User-Agent'])

def is_mobile_capable(self):
    user_agent_lower = self.user_agent().lower()
    return user_agent_lower.find("ipod") > -1 or \
            user_agent_lower.find("ipad") > -1 or \
            user_agent_lower.find("iphone") > -1 or \
            user_agent_lower.find("webos") > -1 or \
            user_agent_lower.find("android") > -1
```

The full code can be found at https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Repo/Website/Group/stable/File/request_handler.py#115

Basically, the browser is mobile if the lower-cased User-Agent request header contains the string ipod, ipad, iphone, webos, or android. Once you know the requester is mobile, you can redirect to a mobile url or or customize your output for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. Give it a shot:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 699) {
  document.location = "mobile.html";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Put it just below the body tag.